# Get IPv4 addresses from Dns.GetHostEntry()

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ipv6, ipv4

I've got some code here that works great on IPv4 machines, but on our build server (an IPv6) it fails.  In a nutshell:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty);
```

The documentation for GetHostEntry says that passing in string.Empty will get you the IPv4 address of the localhost.  This is what I want.  The problem is that it's returning the string "::1:" on our IPv6 machine, which I believe is the IPv6 address.

Pinging the machine from any other IPv4 machine gives a good IPv4 address... and doing a **"ping -4 machinename"** from itself gives the correct IPv4 address.... but pinging it regularly from itself gives "::1:".

How can I get the IPv4 for this machine, from itself?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Have you looked at [all the addresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist(VS.80).aspx) in the return, discard the ones of [family InterNetworkV6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily(VS.80).aspx) and retain only the IPv4 ones?

Comment: My call is only returning ipv6, no ipv4 entries. If I do `Resolve-DnsName -Type A` in PowerShell I get the IPv4 back (default type it returns in this case is AAAA).

Comment: @subkamran please ask that as a separate question, not as a comment

Comment: It's due to Direct Access on my corporate PC. Disregard.

Comment: Why can't we use IPv6?

Comment: @StormMuller because the OP asks "Get IPv4 addresses..."

Answer (score 52):

To find all local IPv4 addresses:

```
IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
    Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
    a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

or use `Array.Find` or `Array.FindLast` if you just want one.

Answer (score 13):

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(serverName);
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Comment: Unfortunately is the VirtualBox-address before computer ip address on my machine. I can't select the real ip address because both have the "InterNetwork" flag.

Answer (score 5):

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string myHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        string myIP = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].IsIPv6LinkLocal == false)
            {
                myIP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost).AddressList[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Declare myIP and myHost in public Variable
and use in any function of the form.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static string GetIPAddress(string hostname)
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LocalIPadress: " + ip);
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To find all valid address list this is the code I have used

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAddresses()
{
      var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
      return (from ip in host.AddressList where ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.lo select ip.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get all [IPv4 address](https://myipv4address.com/) from the DNS using this code:

```
IPs[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
           Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
           address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Answer (score -5):

**IPv6**

lblIP.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(0).ToString()

**IPv4**

lblIP.Text = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName).AddressList(1).ToString()

Comment: System.Net.Dns.GetHostName is a method, not a property.

Comment: can get 2 of ipv6 , 0 not equal  ipv4, can be another set of ipv6