# Get IP address through c# (in IPv4 value)

Tags: c#, networking, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get IPv4 addresses from Dns.GetHostEntry()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059526/get-ipv4-addresses-from-dns-gethostentry)

I try the following code to get my IP address, in XP, it returns the IP address V4 format,
but when I do it in my system(windows 7), it return the ip address in v6 format.

How do to solve this?

Code

```
try
{
      //iphostname = Dns.GetHostName();  // Resolving Host name
      IPHostEntry ipentry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostLabel.Text);
      IPAddress[] addr = ipentry.AddressList;// Resolving IP Addresses
      for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
      {
           try
           {
               ipLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(addr[i]) + "\r\n";
           }
           catch
           {
               ipLabel.Text += "IP Address            | " + "\r\n";
           }
      }
}
catch
{
     //richTextBox1.Text += "Hostname             | " + "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059526/get-ipv4-addresses-from-dns-gethostentry

Comment: "the IP address" doesn't exist - a machine can have multiple IP address. And v6 and v4 addresses aren't two representations of the same thing - a v6 address is separate from a v4 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 string strHostName = "";
 strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
 IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
 IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
 ipLabel.Text = addr[addr.Length - 2].ToString();
```

Comment: yes..it is working..,so the magic is add "-2"  behind the length? =)

Comment: IPv4 address is at the 2nd index of `AddressList`, and the length of `AddressList` is 4. So `AddressList[4 - 2]` = `AddressList[2]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
try
           {
               ipLabel.Text += Convert.ToString(addr[i]) + ";";
           }
```

Since IPv6 is enabled in windows 7 it will return both IPv4 and IPv6 ,and your loop is erasing a few values.