# c# socket connect addressfamily

Tags: c#, sockets, ftp

I have a function to connect to my ftp

```
   clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unspecified, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(remoteAddress).AddressList[0], remotePort));
```

But, with some computers, this doesn't work.
The exception is

> The system detected an invalid pointer address when it tried to use a pointer argument of a call.

If I change AddressFamily.Unspecified to AddressFamily.InterNetwork, problem is solved.
I have to understand why there is this problem, why the original code works with certains computers but not with everyone...
If someone could help me :)

Comment: May this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12924286/2630261 ?

Answer (score 2):

When using `AddressFamily.Unspecified`, you are probably using the first address which can be IPv6 and not IPv4. From this [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see that using `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` uses the IPv4 address.

It is probably safer to get all the addresses and then use the first IPv4 address. This answer will show you how: [Get IPv4 addresses from Dns.GetHostEntry()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059526/get-ipv4-addresses-from-dns-gethostentry/1059562#1059562)

Comment: Thank you for the anwer. I tried IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(remoteAddress);
                for (int index = 0; index < hostInfo.AddressList.Length; index++)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(hostInfo.AddressList[index].ToString());
                } It returns just one IP address and it is an IPv4

Comment: Did you try it on the computer where the exception is triggered?

Comment: yes, i have it on my computer (precedent dev hadn't it, with another computer)