# c# fail to generate code in server

Tags: c#

```
            string ipname;
            string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
            ipname = Convert.ToString(ipEntry.AddressList[1]);
            string cleanIP = ipname.Replace(".", string.Empty);
            string ipnew = cleanIP.Substring(6);
            string full_app_code = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmddhhmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) + ipnew + "H";
```

My result for "full_app_code" work fine when run in localhost,
full_app_code ="201632221032461247H",
why when i try to generate the full_app_code in production server it fail to generate,
the output i get is ="20161823091804389d:2895:83f2:d3e2%17H"

Comment: So what is wrong with what you get? Hint: ipv6

Comment: Here is another hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059526/get-ipv4-addresses-from-dns-gethostentry

Comment: @zerkms ,tried this (IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
     Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
     a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);) but not working :(

Comment: Not sure what "not working" means.

Comment: Please clarify what you expect... Also please update title of your post "generate code" usually means creating some sort of C#/IL code... somewhat unrelated to what is shown in the post.

Answer (score 1):

add this (`using System.Net.Sockets;`)

```
var ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
var ipAddressOfMachine = ipHostEntry.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(addressListItem => addressListItem.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```